# How to scrape particular data within the double curly braces in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to scrape a particular data from string within the double curly { } from a website.  How can one manage to take out this data? Below is the snip of the double curly from the website:

```
<div class="swatch-data">
{"thumbnailImageUrl":"https://www.jbl.com.ph/dw/image/v2/AAUJ_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_Harman/default/dw367304ef/JBL_Endurance-SPRINT_Product-Image_Black_Front-1605x1605px.jpg?sw=270&amp;sh=330&amp;sm=fit&amp;sfrm=png","productUrl":"https://www.jbl.com.ph/JBL+Endurance+SPRINT.html?cgid=in-ear-headphones&amp;dwvar_JBL%20Endurance%20SPRINT_color=Black-GLOBAL-","productSupportUrl":"","productID":"JBLENDURSPRINTBLK","orderable":false,"availability":{"message":"","status":"NOT_AVAILABLE"},"price":{"unitLabel":"each","priceType":"standard","salesPrice":"N/A"},"realprice":{"salesPrice":"N/A"},"badges":["new"],"buttonText":"Sold Out","showProdLimit":{"status":""},"CTAEnable":true,"commerceSiteFlag":false,"showPromoTimerFlag":false,"isProProd":false}
</div>
```

Thank you.

Edit:
PS. I do use BeautifulSoup4, only I am really just a noob, and hasn't come to JSON yet.

Comment: What are you trying to extract?

Comment: What you tried ? Because you have the tags and is simple with bs4.

Comment: This is why Stack Overflow is losing respect. This question was downvoted because apparently the downvoters couldn't distinguish between JSON and HTML. (PS good question, lukayl.)

Comment: @pkpkpk I want to extract "productID":"JBLENDURSPRINTBLK" from the curly braces.

Comment: @0709_ I am trying with BeautifulSoup4.

Comment: @lukayl you want only value of the `productID` ? or the key also

Comment: The string between brackets is a json string. Python has parsers that will allow you to convert the string to a dictionary using the json package.

Comment: @DrutaRuslan I only need the key. Thank you.

Comment: @lukayl the key will be `productID` the value is `JBLENDURSPRINTBLK` you are sure that you want `productID` ?

Comment: @DrutaRuslan Sorry, I want the value.

Comment: @pkpkpk Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @lukayl check my answer it will give you the value of the `productID`

Answer (score 4):

the example with [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
import bs4
import json

html = """
<div class="swatch-data">
{"thumbnailImageUrl":"https://www.jbl.com.ph/dw/image/v2/AAUJ_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_Harman/default/dw367304ef/JBL_Endurance-SPRINT_Product-Image_Black_Front-1605x1605px.jpg?sw=270&amp;sh=330&amp;sm=fit&amp;sfrm=png","productUrl":"https://www.jbl.com.ph/JBL+Endurance+SPRINT.html?cgid=in-ear-headphones&amp;dwvar_JBL%20Endurance%20SPRINT_color=Black-GLOBAL-","productSupportUrl":"","productID":"JBLENDURSPRINTBLK","orderable":false,"availability":{"message":"","status":"NOT_AVAILABLE"},"price":{"unitLabel":"each","priceType":"standard","salesPrice":"N/A"},"realprice":{"salesPrice":"N/A"},"badges":["new"],"buttonText":"Sold Out","showProdLimit":{"status":""},"CTAEnable":true,"commerceSiteFlag":false,"showPromoTimerFlag":false,"isProProd":false}
</div>
"""

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
js_data = json.loads(soup.find('div').text)

# if you want productID just get it
print(js_data['productID'])
```

**Output**

```
JBLENDURSPRINTBLK
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see in there is actually a [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

You first of all need to take out the div. Using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is one of the recommended methods.

Then, you can load the string using `json.loads(str)`.